# Core Data group by AND sort

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by, ios6

I've made a core data query to sum cost grouped by 3 columns (npi, po, and nit)

```
NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.ce"]];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[ex setName:@"sum"];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"npi",@"po", @"nit", ex, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"npi",@"po", @"nit", nil]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Which works perfectly.

But I would like to sort the sum column and If I use a "classic" NSSortDescriptor:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sum" ascending:YES]]];
```

It doesn't work since `sum` is not in the BMA entity

Comment: I don't get the `.ce` bit in your sum expression. Where does that come from? It's not a property you are fetching...

Comment: sum.ce apply the SUM() function to the field "ce"